# Getting INVALID_ARGUMENT exception running a report via Google analytics reporting api

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am submitting this query

```
    {
      "reportRequests":
      [
        {
          "viewId": "xxxxx",
          "dateRanges": [{"startDate": "2021-08-01", "endDate": "2021-10-31"}],
          "dimensions": [{"name": "ga:segment"}],
          "metrics": [{"expression": "ga:users"}],
          "filtersExpression": "ga:pagePath~=en-US/companies/Primary/",
          ""segments"": [{""segmentId"": ""gaid::xxxxxxx""}]
        }
      ]
    }
```

And getting this result:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid value 'ga:pagePath~=en-US/companies/Primary/' for filters parameter.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
      }
    }
```

Am I incorrect in my reading of the Google analytics reporting API v4 docs that "filterExpression" takes the same syntax as Google analytics core reporting api v3?

Comment: Which type of Google analytics account do you have exactly.  Universal analytics or GA4?

Comment: This is Universal

Comment: I'd meant to use "V4 API" in title

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to change the title. How does one do that?